# The position of the bar plot

Tags: stata

I have the following plot with the code:

```
graph bar mean_positive, over(agegroup)
```

How could I generate a bar plot with YA on the left, MA in the middle, and OA on the right?

[bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQa4w.png)

Comment: This is well explained in `help graph bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's guess that `agegroup` is a string variable, in which case

```
label def agegroup 1 YA 2 MA 3 OA 
encode agegroup, gen(age) label(agegroup)
```

will get your categories in order and you can try again with `age`. This is a good time to be less cryptic and use longer labels and even give the exact age limits.

Another guess is that you have a numeric variable with value labels in a poor order, in which case reach first for `recode`.